# Can throwing charged capacitors cause magnetic fields?

Tags: capacitor, current, electromagnetism, charge, magnetic-flux

Since current is just buckets of charge passing through a point in space per unit time, and a capacitor is a literal bucket of charge, I had some questions in mind.

- Is throwing a charged capacitor considered electrical current? Like if the capacitor is say 1 inch in length, has 1C of charge, and is flying through the air at  100 inches per second, does that mean 100 amps of current?
- If so, would magnetic fields be generated? Would it actually take more effort to throw a charged capacitor than to throw an uncharged one, since the supposed magnetic field stores part of the work done in throwing?
- If the capacitor is left on the desk, and an observer moves instead, would he/she see magnetic fields, but a stationary one doesn't?

I know this is silly and trivial, but I don't have iron filings and a large supercap.

Comment: Do(n't) charged capacitors attract/repell each other? Why (not)? What does that say about their total charge?

Comment: When throwing a charged capacitor across the workshop at someone while shouting “catch” the reaction was usually the best... but no we never did that :) ...

Comment: Oh, btw these were the capacitors that were used in distributors so smal...

Comment: I was going to answer based on what happens if you throw *half* a capacitor (ie a single charged object) around, but you've already accepted an answer. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_Electric_Bell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One plate on a capacitor is positively charged and the other plate is negatively charged. Net charge on a capacitor is therefore zero. Does that help? Do we see magnetic fields generated by the charged capacitor if we placed it at the equator (rotating about 1000 mph).

Comment: What if the capacitor is very big, like 10m long? :) And if you have a twisted pair, don't you see a very weak magnetic field right close to the wires?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum ask your self how much voltage is needed to achieve 1 coulomb with plates 10m apart. Yes, twisted pairs have a weak magnetic field close to 1 wire relative to the other.

Comment: I don't think the question was quantitative. Besides, C/V is not that complicated :)

Comment: Just a little (not more than 1mg) more seriously, imagine throwing a Van Der Graaf generator :D

Comment: Throwing a VDGG doesn't sound trivial but if you did throw it and also spun it you would likely create an nice EM wave at the spin frequency.

Comment: Yes! I could even modulate a low frequency message to the other side of earth! It's flat, so propagation is not an issue.